# how to use session in multiple inputs?[php]

Tags: php

```
for ($i=0; $i <count($_POST['name']) ; $i++) { 

                    if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['NIK'])) 
                    {
                        $_SESSION['NIK'][$i] = $_POST['NIK'][$i];
                        $NIK = $_SESSION['NIK'][$i];
                        $_SESSION['name'][$i] = $_POST['name'][$i];
                        $name= $_SESSION['name'][$i];

                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jabatan AS t JOIN karyawn AS s WHERE  s.id_jabatan LIKE t.id_jabatan AND s.nama_karyawan LIKE '%{$nama_karyawan}%' AND s.NIK LIKE '%{$NIK}%' ");
                        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                        $_SESSION['job_name'] = $row['job_name'];
                        $_SESSION['division'] = $row['division'];
                    }

                ?>
```

I wanna ask how to use session in multiple input? 
because when I change the page and return back to that page, it show error

> Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\training\output_main.php on
>   line 22

it means for code `for ($i=0; $i <count($_POST['name']) ; $i++)`

please help how to my session working, i'm just learning PHP.

Comment: You must put `session_start();` at the top of every PHP page using session variables.

Comment: i did, but stil not working...

Comment: if you have session_start and its not working, probably it was never set. try var_dump($_SESSION); after session_start() see what it has, debug from there.

Answer (score -1):

I think the sessions are not the problem but if you go back to this page I guess there is no $_POST['name'] anymore.

you need to check if your $_POST['name'] is not empty

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
   $postName = $_POST['name'];
}  elseif (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
   $postName = $_SESSION['name'];
} else {
   Die('no post or session.');
}

for ($i=0; $i <count($postName) ; $i++)

                if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['NIK'])) 
                {
                    $_SESSION['NIK'][$i] = $_POST['NIK'][$i];
                    $NIK = $_SESSION['NIK'][$i];
                    $_SESSION['name'][$i] = $_POST['name'][$i];
                    $name= $_SESSION['name'][$i];

                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jabatan AS t JOIN karyawn AS s WHERE  s.id_jabatan LIKE t.id_jabatan AND s.nama_karyawan LIKE '%{$nama_karyawan}%' AND s.NIK LIKE '%{$NIK}%' ");
                    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                    $_SESSION['job_name'] = $row['job_name'];
                    $_SESSION['division'] = $row['division'];
                }

            ?>
```

Comment: yes right, there is no $_POST['name'] if i go back. so how can i solved this problem? please help because i have no more idea with this error..

Comment: and also check the isset:
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['NIK'])).

if there is no $_POST['name'] the for loop would not work.